# cmake OpenCV don't generate symlink shared library

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

I am trying to generate OpenCV 4.6.0 world shared libraries for Qt's qmake. The problem is that it's generating symlinks of `libopencv_world.so` and `libopencv_world.so.406` that links to `libopencv_world.so.4.6.0`.

I don't want to generate symlinks, all I want to generate is a standalone shared library with `libopencv_world.so`. The reason for this is that when building the Qt app, it's looking for `libopencv_world.so` but when running it, it's looking for `libopencv_world.so.406`. Now if I create two files of `libopencv_world.so.406` and `libopencv_world.so`, everything is working fine. Now the issue with this is that I have duplicate files.

In Qt, I have `LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Libs/opencv2/precompiled/linux_release/ -lopencv_world`

Is there a way to generate only `libopencv_world.so` without any symlinks?

This is what I have tried so far (in cmake properties):

1. I tried settings `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` to `-fno-version`, in this case the main shared library is not built but the symlink files are built, and pointing to the main file which does not exist
2. I tried setting `VERSION` and `SOVERSION` to empty string and that doesn't work too

Any help on this is much appreciated.

**Update 1**

I have setup `VERSION` and `SOVERSION` to an empty string in cmake-gui as below

[image]

Comment: Clearing VERSION and SOVERSION properties is a correct way for disable generation of SOVERSION. These properties are set there: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake#L1022. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: [SOVERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOVERSION.html) and [VERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VERSION.html) are **properties**, not *variables*. You cannot set them in CMake GUI, you need to modify the **code** of OpenCV project.

Comment: That actually worked. Commenting out  `set_target_properties(${the_module} PROPERTIES
     VERSION ${OPENCV_LIBVERSION}
      SOVERSION ${OPENCV_SOVERSION}
  )`. If you add it as the answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev suggested. Commenting out

```
  # For dynamic link numbering conventions
  if(NOT ANDROID)
    # Android SDK build scripts can include only .so files into final .apk
    # As result we should not set version properties for Android
    set_target_properties(${the_module} PROPERTIES
      VERSION ${OPENCV_LIBVERSION}
      SOVERSION ${OPENCV_SOVERSION}
    )
  endif()
```

From https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake#L1017-L1025 and rebuilding the code will generate only one shared object - `libopencv_world.so`, provided it is built with `-D BUILD_opencv_world`.